# Search and Replace Multiple Words

Tags: vba, ms-word

I already have the code to do a search and replace in Microsoft Word using a VBA macro, but at the moment, my code is copying and pasting the same function multiple times.

What I would like to do is have an dictionary of words that need to be replaced, so for example:

old_word: new_word

Then I have the VBA script to loop through and make the necessary changes in the document.

My code for now is and repeats for each new word pair.

```
Sub change_words()

   With Selection.Find
        .Text = "optimize"
        .Replacement.Text = "optimise"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .MatchWholeWord = True
   End With

   Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

   With Selection.Find
        .Text = "utilized"
        .Replacement.Text = "utilised"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .MatchWholeWord = True
   End With

   Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

End Sub
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

```
Sub change_words(ByVal findWord, byVal replaceWord)

   With Selection.Find
        .Text = findWord
        .Replacement.Text = replaceWord
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .MatchWholeWord = True
   End With
   Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

If you change your function to accept parameters as shown, you can call it in a loop, and (for example) pass in the values you want like so:

```
Dim myDict : Set myDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
myDict("optimize") = "optimise"
myDict("utilized") = "utilised"
For myLoop = 0 to myDict.Count - 1
    change_words myDict.Keys()(myLoop), myDict.Items()(myLoop)
Next
```

That should allow you to reuse the code without repeating it.

Comment: is there a way to quickly make this work with regex in word?